# Encoding Issues �

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, utf-8

Getting the symbol from the above and I'm at a loss what I'm missing.
What I've done so far.

Set on header

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

Database output charset: UTF8

```
$char = mysqli_character_set_name($conn);
echo "The current character set is: $char\n";
```

Set on file.

```
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
```

File is: `UTF 8`
Database Table is: `utf8_general_ci`

EDIT: SHOW TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE `testimonials` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`showflag` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '10',
`heading` varchar(155) DEFAULT NULL,
`testimonial` longtext NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`domain` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`date` date NOT NULL,
`image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`rating` int(1) DEFAULT '5',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=47 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

EDIT: Database storage is fine, the issue occurs on output only.

Comment: Is it stored as that in the DB or on outputting it comes out as that? Please show which `meta` you are now using.

Comment: @chris85 Issue only on output. Removed the 2nd meta and only using. <meta charset="UTF-8" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a contradiction with the two meta clauses -- use the same charset.

Look for "black diamond" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; the *column* is the important part.

Comment: Table and columns are set to  utf8_general_ci, Also updated post above for `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Comment: Also weird thing is, outputting via ajax on the backend of the site is fine. but outputting it in the front of the site shows the black "?" could it be possible it's a wordpress issue or plugin?

Comment: Check the final generated output by viewing source in the browser. Any other meta tags overriding your charset?

Comment: @ChrisLam source shows. ��� no other meta. Also I've update post above for the actual page.

Comment: Hex is (C390C39EC38620) . symbols are ÐÞÆ

Comment: What were you expecting?  Any of these:?   cp932, sjis   9  3 'ﾃ静榲'
                                        euckr   9  3 '횖횧횈'
                                          gbk   9  3 '脨脼脝' ?

Comment: Or did you really want ÐÞÆ?

Comment: Was that the hex from `SELECT HEX(col) ...` ?  Or inside the app?

Comment: expecting these ÐÞÆ

Comment: Check the encoding being used in the browser.  Chrome?  FF?  Other?

Comment: `C390C39EC386` is the correct utf8 (or utf8mb4) encoding for `ÐÞÆ`.

Comment: So, I am pretty sure the browser is screwing it up.

Comment: @RickJames Hi Rick, checked chrom using `document.characterSet` returned UTF-8. I've isolated my code here and restarting everything you set on your guide https://www.webvisions.com/test.php

Comment: @RickJames Resolved the issue, the cause was I wrote `mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");` in a function and I neglected to check if it was being carried over to another function. Reviewing your guide help me. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  `mysqli_set_charset` does not need to be called but once at the beginning of a connection.  I hope you are not unnecessarily reconnecting.

Comment: @RickJames I was doing something like. `func utf8(){ declare } utf8(); func fetch(){} and I included that php file. I moved the utf8(); call inside the fetch function and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

You are setting charset to `iso-8859-1`..Try changing it to `utf-8`

Your second meta tag is only useful only for HTML4 though. For modern browsers that work well with HTML5, having only `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` is good enough.